# Enable Police in CXF 3.0 and Spring with Contract-First

Tags: spring, web-services, wsdl, cxf, ws-security

I'm trying implement WS-Policy in my services with CXF 3.1.0 and Spring 4.1.6

Most of examples that I found was with CXF 2 and structures like cxf-extension-policy.xml and cxf-extension-ws-security.xml changed in CXF new version.

I tried something like:

```
package spring;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

import org.apache.cxf.Bus;
import org.apache.cxf.feature.AbstractFeature;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl;
import org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.WSPolicyFeature;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;

import com.student.StudentService;
import com.student.service.StudentServiceImpl;

@Configuration
@ImportResource({"classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"})
public class CXFConfig {

@Autowired
private Bus cxfBus;

@Bean
public StudentService service(){
    return new StudentServiceImpl();
}

@Autowired
@Bean
public Endpoint serviceImpl(
        final StudentService service){

    EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(this.cxfBus, service);
    endpoint.setAddress("/StudentService");
    endpoint.publish();

    return endpoint;
}
}
```

My WSDL have some policies and is basically the WSDL from [this tutorial](http://www.javatips.net/blog/2012/08/cxf-with-usernametoken-ws-security-policy)

I generate my Java classes using Contract-first.

When I run my project my policies don't appears.

I tried

```
final Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
properties.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, WSHandlerConstants.USERNAME_TOKEN);
properties.put(WSHandlerConstants.PASSWORD_TYPE, WSConstants.PW_TEXT);
properties.put(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_REF, ServerPasswordCallback.class.getName());

EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(this.cxfBus, portType);
endpoint.setProperties(properties);
endpoint.setAddress("/StudentService");
endpoint.publish();

return endpoint;
```

I also tryed

```
final Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
properties.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, WSHandlerConstants.USERNAME_TOKEN);
properties.put(WSHandlerConstants.PASSWORD_TYPE, WSConstants.PW_TEXT);
properties.put(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_REF, ServerPasswordCallback.class.getName());

cxfBus.getFeatures().add(new WSPolicyFeature());
cxfBus.getInInterceptors().add(new WSS4JInInterceptor(properties));

EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(this.cxfBus, portType);
endpoint.setAddress("/StudentService");
endpoint.publish();

return endpoint;
```

And

```
WSPolicyFeature wsPolicyFeature = new WSPolicyFeature();
wsPolicyFeature.initialize(this.cxfBus);
```

None of this works.

Does someone knows how to configure this with Spring annotations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a while, I discover that WSS4J uses the idea of interceptor instead of policies in contract.

I changed my spring implementation to

```
    EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(this.cxfBus, flightService);
    endpoint.setAddress("/FlightService");
    endpoint.setWsdlLocation("src/main/resources/wsdls/flightservice_v1r1.wsdl");
    endpoint.getProperties().put("ws-security.callback-handler", new ServerPasswordCallback());
    endpoint.publish();
```

However, even with that configuration when I deployed my contract it showed 2 wsdl:binding and 2 wsdl:service...

I found than another way to solve my problem and less couple than the first one, I externalize my policies in a XML file and anotated my service with

```
@Policies({
  @Policy(uri="classpath:policies/usernameToken.xml", includeInWSDL=true)
})
```

My Spring configuration was reduced to

```
EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(this.cxfBus, new FlightServiceImpl());
endpoint.setAddress("/FlightService");
endpoint.getProperties().put("ws-security.callback-handler", new ServerPasswordCallback());
endpoint.publish();
```

When I deploy me project, finally I see

```
<wsdl:service name="FlightServiceImplService">
  <wsdl:port binding="tns:FlightServiceImplServiceSoapBinding" name="FlightServiceImplPort">
    <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/ws-security/FlightService"/>
  </wsdl:port>
  <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#authenticationPolicy"/>
</wsdl:service>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, my problem wasn't in CXF/ Spring configuration... was in WSDL that I expected when depoy.

I was expecting something like this:

```
<wsdl:binding name="ChangeStudentDetailsImplServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:ChangeStudentDetails">
  <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#ChangeStudentDetailsImplServiceSoapBindingPolicy"/>
  <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
  <wsdl:operation name="changeName">
    <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
    <wsdl:input name="changeName">
      <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output name="changeNameResponse">
      <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>

<wsdl:service name="ChangeStudentDetailsImplService">
  <wsdl:port binding="tns:ChangeStudentDetailsImplServiceSoapBinding" name="ChangeStudentDetailsImplPort">
    <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#ChangeStudentDetailsImplServiceSoapBindingPolicy"/>
    <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/ws-policy/ChangeStudent"/>
  </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

However, when I use the Contract-First approach I received:

```
<wsdl:binding name="ChangeStudentDetailsImplServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:ChangeStudentDetails">
  <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
  <wsdl:operation name="changeName">
    <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
    <wsdl:input name="changeName">
      <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output name="changeNameResponse">
      <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>

<wsdl:service name="ChangeStudentDetailsImplService">
  <wsdl:port binding="tns:ChangeStudentDetailsImplServiceSoapBinding" name="ChangeStudentDetailsImplPort">
    <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/ws-policy/ChangeStudent"/>
  </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

So I thought that wasn't work.

I changed my CXF/ Spring configuration to

```
@Autowired
@Bean
public Endpoint serviceImpl(
        final ChangeStudentDetails portType){

    Map<String, Object> inProps = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    inProps.put("action", "UsernameToken");
    inProps.put("passwordType", "PasswordText");
    inProps.put("passwordCallbackClass", ServerPasswordCallback.class.getName());

    EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(this.cxfBus, portType);
    endpoint.getInInterceptors().add(new WSS4JInInterceptor(inProps));
    endpoint.setAddress("/StudentService");
    endpoint.publish();

    return endpoint;
}
```

When I execute this through SOAPUI I set the type of authentication, username and password and works. I just don't understand yet why my polices don't show up

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this to load an external policy:

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(String filePath);
Map<String, Object> requestContext = ((BindingProvider)client).getRequestContext();
PolicyBuilder builder = bus.getExtension(org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyBuilder.class);
try {
  Policy wsSecuritypolicy = builder.getPolicy(is);
  requestContext.put(PolicyConstants.POLICY_OVERRIDE, wsSecuritypolicy);
}
catch (Exception e) {
  throw new RuntimeException(e.toString());

}

requestContext.put(SecurityConstants.CALLBACK_HANDLER, MyCallBackClass.class.getName());
```